# Arrays dont want to cooperate while using PHP and JS with Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, arrays

This is very strange problem and I really dont know what should I do.

I take array workers from MySQL database with json_encode
Then i copy it to two other arrays on which I will make operations soon

```
var workers = <?php echo json_encode($tablica_pracownikow); ?>;
var toSort = workers;
var sort = workers;
```

Then I have a function drawForFirst which display workers array

```
function drawForFirst(){
  for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
      $('.main_element').append(workers[i][0]);
      $('.main_element').append(workers[i][1]);
      $('.main_element').append(workers[i][2]);
      $('.main_element').append(workers[i][3]);
      $('.main_element').append(workers[i][4]);
      $('.main_element').append(workers[i][5]);
      $('.main_element').append(workers[i][6]);
}
```

I have three simillar functions for all three arrays.

BUT, when I make change in one of the arrays, like change one row of data into 0, and then I use any other draw function, all tables are displayed  this same.
If I make change in toSort, and then I want to draw sort, changes from toSort are appearing.

What is happening!?!

Comment: If you really wanted to name your variable `sort`, why did you call it `workers` ?

Comment: In JavaScript objects are always references. You need to clone those arrays.

Comment: thats because workers, toSort, and sort are all references to the same object.  you'll need to copy the array if you want to be able to update their values independently.

Answer (score 2):

If that's an array, you can use `slice()` to return a copy of the array, as right now you're referencing the same array in all three variables :

```
var workers = <?php echo json_encode($tablica_pracownikow); ?>;
var toSort = workers.slice(0);
var sort = workers.slice(0);
```

You could of course also echo the JSON to each variable:

```
var workers = <?php echo json_encode($tablica_pracownikow); ?>;
var toSort  = <?php echo json_encode($tablica_pracownikow); ?>;
var sort    = <?php echo json_encode($tablica_pracownikow); ?>;
```

That would certainly create three different arrays with the exact same content, but depending on the length of the JSON string, `slice()` could be more efficient then parsing the same string three times, but you'll probably never notice the difference anyway.

Comment: REALLY! BUT HOW! How can I reference to this same array when i have it in three different variables. Anyway, thank you! You saved my life :)

Comment: How what? Just setting `var newVar = oldArray` makes both variables reference the same array, so when changing the old array, newVar also changes, as it's the exact same array. You can either echo the JSON to each variable, or use slice to copy the array.

Comment: Sorry, it is still not working. I added slice at the end and nothing changes...

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating new array, you are just creating new references to the same array

You can do this to copy array in different variables -

```
var workers = <?php echo json_encode($tablica_pracownikow); ?>;
var toSort = workers.slice(0);
var sort = workers.slice(0);
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but it still do not work. I made those changes, but nothing happens :(

Comment: @MateuszC What do you mean by _nothing happens_, ? do you get any error ?

Comment: Hi, now everything is working, thankt to not thie slice method, but three times json. 
Thank you all for help :)